# Switches on eclipse

Tags: java

Why is the output `"ADC"` and where the `D` came from ? Also, what is the goal of the `default` and `continue` commands in this code?

```
char x = 'A';
while(x != 'D') {
    switch(x) {
    case 'A':
        System.out.print(x); x = 'D';
    case 'B':
        System.out.print(x); x = 'C';
    case 'C':
        System.out.print(x); x = 'D';
    default:
        continue;
 }
```

Comment: Because there is no `break;`

Comment: Read [The Java Tutorials: The `switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: @Tunaki what do u mean by there is no break? like there is only Case A , B and C where did D come from? and if the switch finds no case does it mean it default outputs the x?

Comment: From `case A`, which sets `x=D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with `A`. Since `x != 'D'` you enter the `while` loop.
Now the flow is the following:

- enter `case 'A'`
- print `A` and assign `x = 'D'`
- fall-through to `case 'B'`
- print `D` (since `x == 'D'`) and assign `x = 'C'`
- fall-through to `case 'C'`
- print `C` (since `x == 'C'`) and assign `x = 'D'`
- fall-through to `default` (which will normally be reached, when you can't find a matching `case`)
- `continue` (which means return to the start of the `while` loop)
- Since `x == 'D'` the condition evaluates to `false` and won't enter the loop.

==> Result: `ADC` is printed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you forgot the `break`s between the steps. So all steps after the matching case will be executed. Try it with:

```
switch (x) {
    case 'A':
         System.out.print(x);
         x = 'D';
         break;
    case 'B':
         System.out.print(x);
         x = 'C';
         break;
    case 'C':
         System.out.print(x);
         x = 'D';
         break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch statements have what is called ["fall through"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).

You need a `break` at the end of every case, otherwise all of them will run, as is happening here.

```
char x = 'A'; //starts off as A
while(x != 'D') {
    switch(x) {
    case 'A':
        System.out.print(x); x = 'D'; //here is gets printed and changed to D
    case 'B': //you fall through here because there's no break
        System.out.print(x); x = 'C'; //print again then change to C
    case 'C': //fall through again
        System.out.print(x); x = 'D'; //print again then change to D
    default:
        continue;
```

You only enter the `case` if it matches (so if it starts as C it will only print once) but once a match is found you can fall through to the other cases as well.

If you add `break`s, then you won't fall through anymore.

```
char x = 'A';
while(x != 'D') {
    switch(x) {
    case 'A': //match
        System.out.print(x); x = 'D'; //print then modify
        break; //break
    case 'B':
        System.out.print(x); x = 'C';
        break;
    case 'C':
        System.out.print(x); x = 'D';
        break;
    default:
        continue;
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this switch:

```
int a = 0;
switch(a) {
case 0:
    System.out.println("0");
case 1:
    System.out.println("1");
}
```

The lines of code which are executed are:

1. `int a = 0;`
2. `System.out.println("0");`
3. `System.out.println("1");`

In order to only execute the statement you want to execute you have to use `break` at the end of every case:

```
int a = 0;
switch(a) {
case 0:
    System.out.println("0");
    break;
case 1:
    System.out.println("1");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When first time switch executes, case 'A' selected, prints A and set x to 'D',
There no break between cases, so next line executes - print D (as x set to 'D' before) and set x to 'C'. And so on.